# x86 bootstrapping kernel from separate kernel.asm (nasm)

Tags: assembly, nasm

I've written a bootstrap for the bootsector.  That bootstrap is trying to load a kernel from a stage 2 on the second sector.

If I include the kernel within the same asm, everything works as expected.  if I dd the kernel.bin from the kernel.asm to an offset of 512 bytes into the disk image, it does not do the same thing, even with the exact same code.  Instead, it prints jibberish.

My code to read the second sector and execute it is as follows...

```
read_first_byte:
  pusha
  mov ah, 0             ; reset disk
  mov dl, [boot_drive]  ; drive 0
  stc
  int 13h
  jc rs_fail      ; return, we're a failure
reset_success:
  mov bx, stage2        ; place in memory 512 bytes past where the MBR is loaded.
  mov ah, 0x02 ; function
  mov al, 0x01 ; sectors to read
  mov ch, 0x00 ; track/cyl
  mov cl, 0x02 ; sector start
  mov dh, 0x00 ; head
  mov dl, [boot_drive] ; drive
  print_hex [boot_drive]
  stc
  int 13h
  jc rs_fail

  print_hex [stage2]
  print_hex [stage2 + 1]
  jmp stage2
  ;jmp disk_return
rs_fail:
  call int13_show_error

;;  mov ds, es
;;  mov si, 512       ; prep lodsb
;;  lodsb             ; load the first byte of the disk sector read - sector 2
disk_return:
  popa
  ret
```

The end of the 512 by section is...

```
    buffer times 510-($-$$) db 0    ; Pad remainder of boot sector with 0s
    dw 0xAA55       ; The standard PC boot signature

stage2:
    mov si, text_string   ; Put string position into SI
    call print_string       ; Call our string-printing routine
    mov si, crlf            ; Put string position into SI
    call print_string       ; Call our string-printing routine
    call read_keys
    jmp $

print_key:
  mov ah, 0         ; 16h read key function
  int 16h           ; al now has character from keyboard
  mov ah, 0Eh       ; TTY output, ah had scan code, we discard
  int 10h           ; prints character in ah

read_keys:
  mov ah, 01h       ; detect key
  int 16h
  jnz print_key     ; only print if key in buffer
    jmp read_keys           ; Jump to read_keys - infinite loop!

    text_string db 'Kernel loaded!', 0
  buffer2 times 1024-($-$$) db 0
```

The kernel.asm is as follows...

```
BITS 16

start:
    mov si, text_string   ; Put string position into SI
    call print_string       ; Call our string-printing routine
    mov si, crlf            ; Put string position into SI
    call print_string       ; Call our string-printing routine
    call read_keys
    jmp $

print_key:
  mov ah, 0         ; 16h read key function
  int 16h           ; al now has character from keyboard
  mov ah, 0Eh       ; TTY output, ah had scan code, we discard
  int 10h           ; prints character in ah

read_keys:
  mov ah, 01h       ; detect key
  int 16h
  jnz print_key     ; only print if key in buffer
    jmp read_keys           ; Jump to read_keys - infinite loop!

print_string:           ; Routine: output string in SI to screen
  push ax
    mov ah, 0Eh     ; int 10h 'print char' function

.repeat:
    lodsb           ; Get character from string
    cmp al, 0
    je .done        ; If char is zero, end of string
    int 10h         ; Otherwise, print it
    jmp .repeat

.done:
  pop ax
    ret

    crlf db 0x0a,0x0d,0
    text_string db 'Kernel loaded!', 0
```

Both the bootstrap and kernel are assembled with the following, in case I want to use gdb...

```
  nasm -f elf -g -o file.elf file.asm
  objcopy -O binary file.elf file.bin
```

For a working example, I've got my tiny-os on github.  The "kernel" branch is the one where I'm assembling the kernel from a separate kernel.asm file.  The specific point in time is at https://github.com/TrentonAdams/tinyos/tree/0524a1af9de7b3e58c7e2c0660f587d4c8573e98

```
 make clean test # runs qemu with the single myfirst.asm code
 make clean kernel # runs qemu with a disk image that has the kernel.bin in the second sector.
```

In an effort to keep this stack overflow post a standalone post of it's own, not requiring any external links, please let me know if the contents of the post are enough to answer the question.  i.e. if you actually needed to know something from github, that wasn't in this post, let me know and I can update it.

Answer (score 4):

You have a mismatch of actual `ds` and assumed `org`. Fix either of those so they match. If you didn't use an `org` in the file it defaults to zero, so you need to set up `ds` such that it points to the load address, e.g. `mov ax, 0x7e0; mov ds, ax` before passing control to the second sector. Alternatively, use the proper `org`, e.g. `org 0x200` to tell the assembler that it's a continuation of the first sector.

Comment: ha, I knew it had to be some ort of offset thing I didn't understand.  Thanks so much!  I totally should have posted a question earlier.

Why does it work when loading the second sector if both pieces of code are in the same file?

Comment: Because then the assembler obviously sees that the second comes after the first. The location counter is incremented automatically within the same file, but if you start a new file how should the assembler know where to start? It will need some help from you. Note that `org` is typically used for plain binaries, since you use `elf` format that approach might not work. You will need to adjust `ds` or possibly use a linker to combine your objects before creating a single binary.